# PostgreSQL - return n-sized varchar from function

Tags: postgresql

As I found in documentation:

> Parenthesized type modifiers (e.g., the precision field for type
>   numeric) are discarded by CREATE FUNCTION

Are there any alternatives to return varchar(N) type from plpgsql function?

---

**question update:**

On picture you can see that Name column recognised as varchar(128), however Number column is recognised as nonsized varchar

[image: Result example]

f_concat function returns: cast(res as varchar(255));

Comment: Why do you think you need that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 
One old Delphi program see everything without length as TEXT BLOB. So if I select fields from varchar(255) column it shows correctly as varchar(255), but if I use function on that column result then result is character varying even if I make cast as varchar(255) inside the function.

Comment: I think the only way is a view which does an explicit cast to `varchar(x)`

Comment: @Ice2burn: We have an old Delphi program with exactly this problem, and we use domains as a workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can preserve the type modifier for a function result by creating a [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html). Postgres will use the underlying `varchar(N)` type when sending column descriptions to your client:

[image]