# Why are PostgreSQL varchar(n) function parameter types overwritten as character varying types?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am trying to resolve an `Exception:42883 - Function does not exist` error when calling a PostgreSQL 13 function from C#.

Most of the 42883 seem to be related to a mismatch between the function signature in PostgreSQL and the C# call.

- I suspect a PostgreSQL parameter of type: `character varying` should be `varchar(255)`.
- However when I drop the original function, change the parameter type from `character varying` to `varchar(255)` in the CREATE script, and execute the CREATE script, the parameter type is always overwritten as `character varying`.

As a test, I did the following:

1. Dropped the function from the database.
2. Modified the script and changed the `fname` parameter from:

   `fname  character varying,`

   To:

   `filename varchar(255),`
3. Executed the CREATE script.
4. The parameter now appears in the function as:

   `filename character varying,`

Is the `character varying` type equivalent to `varchar(n)` and is there a way to set parameter lengths in PostgreSQL 13?

Comment: see this like : https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-char-varchar-text/

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html

Comment: With all function parameters of type: `varchar(n)` forced to `character varying` (and not `character varying(n)`); do you have to the length as another parameter?

Comment: Yes, defining variables with a string data type with a variable length requires a declaration of its length. This logic is the same in all relational database systems.

Comment: I guess that makes sense.  The `varchar(n)` and `character varying(n)` are only useful when defining tables.     They have no utility in functions and stored procedures.

Comment: see the [note](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) section from the doc, and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548219/postgresql-return-n-sized-varchar-from-function?rq=1) that makes use of a domain to circumvent the feature. That being said, you could just check the length of the input and throw an exception if too long

Answer (score 0):

First, [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) says:

> The notations `varchar(n)` and `char(n)` are aliases for `character varying(n)` and `character(n)`, respectively.

The type modifier (the number in parentheses) is ignored for function parameters and results, and no length limits are checked.

The error may well be thrown because PostgreSQL cannot find a match using its [roles for type conversion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html). My advice is to never use `varchar` as data type for function arguments, but the “preferred string data type” `text`. That will make it easier to find a match, and it may well solve your problem.

Comment: When using `text` as datatype => `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dev.conv_list_json(value text)` I still see `varchar` as datatype for function, and get the same issue when a string with more than 256 character is given.

Comment: @Gocht That is not true.

Comment: I can not post images in comments, but I could prove it